# ffmpeg input from images stream out video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to capture a video recording device and would like to add an overlay to it .

I have images being rendered on the fly and I would like to use them as the overlay .

How can I take a set of Images as they are being rendered and use it as an overlay to a video stream ?

Answer (score 5):

**Couldn't wait! Figured it out:**

*I saved an image to the file `out.png` at a fixed frame rate from processing.*

Created a fifo:

```
mkfifo fifo
```

Then in one terminal:

```
tail -f out.png  > fifo
```

Then in another terminal:

```
cat fifo | ffmpeg  -f image2pipe -r 1 -i pipe:0 spo.mp4
```

Making sure to close tail first allowing `ffmpeg` to write the last bit of the file.

Comment: Wow, thats a really nice "hack".